# Probability and Counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A friend of mine gave this for me to solve and I can't figure it out. I fail to see the correlation of houses and classes when we do not know how many people are in each house.

*The students at a boarding school are divided into five houses.  How many students do you need in a class to guarantee that you have at least six students from the same house?*

Comment: How many students can be in a class maximally if from every house there are not more than $5$? And what happens if there is one student more in the class?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when there are six students in a class? Since we have only five houses, there must be one house such that two of its students are in the class. We cannot construct a class of six students where each belongs to a different house!

You could extend this reasoning to six students from a house, and then $n$ students, and then $m$ houses as well, and you will end up with [the Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).